# game map problem, built using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a map for a browser game using jquery. Basically its a grid using divs to display background images for the map content. It uses large divs and then populates those larger divs with smaller ones(for the actual images) once you scroll closer to them. It uses a click and drag event deal.

Now everything works as intended very well im not having a problem with any of that. What i am having a problem with is if you click and your dragging over the map once it goes to populate the next area(it does this because if you were to load the whole map all the time, the performance of the map is rediculusly low) it obviously takes a second or two to load the data and during that time my click and drag event does not work, so it ends up feeling like the map has locked up on you.

So i guess what im looking for is a way of loading data while you can still click and drag or maybe some suggestions on a better way to populated a grid style map. (im currently using a 100x100 (90px per square map) so its like 90000px x 90000px. Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

The base of your question, as I see it, is a way around large operations that can potentially lock up the UI thread of the browser (makes the browser unresponsive). WebWorkers are one solution, but they are not completely cross-browser yet.  Check out the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers

Aside from that, you're just going to have to segment the work.  Also, take a look at your server-side code to see if there is anything more that can be done there before you send the data to the client.  If you *can* do it server-side, do so.  You're taking the burden off the client, and that will improve perceptual performance.

Comment: thank you for the advice, what is wierd is that in chrome or firefox there is virtually no lockup, but on ie8 its huge like 2-5 second mark. What i just spent the last couple of hours doing was changing my loading code from the end of the mouse dragging code to the end of mouse up code. so you can browse all you want but once you stop and un click then it loads, seems like a way better way of handling it, just wish there was a way to speed up this code. but thank you for the info im going to check out the link you sent me.

Answer (score 0):

How are you invoking your function to load the data?  Make sure you load data asynchronously (via Ajax).

Also, you can try queuing up data load requests and execute them only once you stop/complete dragging.

Comment: well what ive done is before hand ive preloaded all of the grid into an array, so thats already done even before the map loads, the large amount of time required to display the data seems to be in adding the divs required. so each time it goes to load up the next section of the map its loading say 3 sections worth of 5x5 of 90x90px, so basically 75 divs that are 90px x 90px. so that seems to take ie8 about 2-5 seconds.